# How do i extract constraintName from Hibernate Exception

Tags: java, hibernate, exception

how to extract the `constraintName` from exception using java,

```
catch(HibernateException e)
        {
            if (ExceptionChecker.isUniqueConstraintViolated(e)) 
            {
                if (log.isDebugEnabled()) {

                    log.debug("save HibernateException" + e.getMessage());

                }

            }
            else
            {   
                throw ExceptionHandler.handleHibernateException(this.getClass().toString(), log, e);
            }
        }
```

above is my java code which catches the exception and it does the desired one but i get the constraint violated exception with constraint name,

my question is how to get the constraint Name from the exception thrown.

i tried this way but it did not work `e.getMessage().split("**")[1]).toString()`

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
try {

} catch(HibernateException e) {
  if(e instanceof ConstraintViolationException) {
    ConstraintViolationException ce = (ConstraintViolationException) e;
    String constraintName = ce.getConstraintName();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Miljenko it worked, i am not able to accept the answer and will accept the answer and +1 :)